# How to allow selecting partial text with the react-native-render-html component?

Tags: react-native-render-html

The react-native-render-html component has a textSelectable property, but when set to true, it enables copying the *entire* text in the component, and doesn't allow highlighting to copy/paste individual text.

Is it possible to allow selecting partial text within the react-native-render-html component?

---

For more context, see the textSelectable property in the react-native-render-html documentation. It allows "all texts to be selected", and when I set it to true that is the clipboard copy behavior I am seeing, but I do not see a configurable property to allow the user to highlight only portions of the text in the component.

Is this a limitation of the library with no viable workaround?

Comment: You need to be more specific, at least provide a code snippet and ideally provide a mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph I meant this as a general question about how the library is supposed to work. I'm seeing the intended behavior of the textSelectable property apparently, but wondering if highlighting partial text is also possible.

I know this is an oddly specific question to ask, but react-native-render-html devs said to ask questions about functionality on SO and not in their Github Issue tracker...

Comment: This is definitely the place to ask! I just didn't understand what you meant by “highlight partial text”, so I proposed that you provide a "user story" to describe the behavior you're looking for.